# Redis to memcache data migration

Tags: redis, migration, memcached

I am using redis 2.4 and i want to store all key in memcache  as a backup .
I am usind Strings as redis data type and I want to store all keys with data in
memcache.

Comment: Step 1: reconsider

Comment: sorry did not get you

Comment: I mean that you better reconsider against this strange architecture. Redis types doesn't map on memcached keys. You'll need (de)serialization mechanism unless you use only string vales in Redis. If you need cold backup - just save `rdb` file, if you need hot backup - setup another Redis instance as slave.

Comment: Yes i am using only string  data type